# GCC adding dereference where there shouldn't be

Tags: gcc, mips, gnu

I'm using `gcc` to compile for `mips32`, and I declare a pointer to a struct called `OSEvent` within a global scope as follows:

```
OSEvent *__osMainEventQueue = NULL;
```

Additionally, code from within a certain function references this pointer during a call to a function:

```
__osEnqueueEvent(event, __osMainEventQueue);
```

That function is declared as follows:

```
extern void __osEnqueueEvent (OSEvent *event, OSEvent *queue);
```

However, when debugging this code, `gcc` seems to dereference the pointer to `__osMainEventQueue` despite me putting nothing there. You can see this in the disassembly as follows:

```
 118:   3c020000    lui v0,0x0
            118: R_MIPS_HI16    __osMainEventQueue
 11c:   8c420000    lw  v0,0(v0)
            11c: R_MIPS_LO16    __osMainEventQueue
 120:   00402825    move    a1,v0
 124:   8fc40018    lw  a0,24(s8)
 128:   0c000000    jal 0 <osScheduleEvent>
            128: R_MIPS_26  __osEnqueueEvent
 12c:   00000000    nop
```

Is there any reason gcc would dereference this pointer? Do I need to reference it with `&`? (This causes a type mismatch warning so I wouldn't consider this a satisfactory explanation / answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no pointer dereference. The code is simply loading the *value* of `__osMainEventQueue` into `$a1` (i.e. the address it points to).

Consider the following scenario: the `__osMainEventQueue` is located at address `0x12345678` and contains the value `0xDEADBEEF`. So what that `lui` and `lw` combo does is to first load `$v0` with the value `0x12340000`. Then it loads from `0x5678($v0)`, i.e. from `(0x12345678)`, so you end up with `0xDEADBEEF` in `$v0`. Never in this code is there an attempt to read from `(0xDEADBEEF)`.

Comment: Thanks! I should have realized __osMainEventQueue relocations point to the address of __osMainEventQueue, not the value. I'd +1 but I don't have enough rep